# Ruby on rails simple form text field value is overridden by default value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, simple-form

I am using a simple form like which has a text field with a default value. Once the user sets their desired value, the default value should be overridden by the user's desired value. But each time the user opens the form to edit it, they see the default value again and again:

```
<%= f.input :notes, input_html: {:value => @order_f.decorate.template_message, rows: 12} %>
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of setting a value, try setting a placeholder like so:

```
<%= f.input :notes_to_deliverer, placeholder: @order_f.decorate.deliverer_template_message, input_html: {rows: 12} %>
```

Comment: Just to clarify _why_ this is happening:

Chances are that the saved value will be the overridden one that the user enters, but when you next render the form, you are re-setting the `:value` option on the page render. 

If you want the default value to be set if the user enters nothing, I would look at having either a `default` setting in your database, or a ActiveRecord Callback that sets it before saving if it is blank.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need the placeholder then you can do it like this:

```
<%= f.input :notes_to_deliverer, input_html: {:value => object.notes_to_deliverer.present? ? object.notes_to_deliverer : @order_f.decorate.deliverer_template_message, rows: 12} %>
```

Here the object is for which you have created the `form`. Also please make sure that this value is saved in database on form submit. And if suppose this your default value to be stored what I mean is if user doesn't enters any value then you need this to be stored then it would be better to use default value at database end. You can set it in migration file.

Hope this helps.